# Snapshot Always Undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

So I am attempting to use Firebase cloud messaging to send push notifications to my app. However, it seems to fail continuously for some odd reason. I am using the onCreate method to listen for the creation of a node under a certain path. It is getting the `UID` from that info gathered in the `onCreate` method but then when I try to get the user info from a different node to grab the fcmToken so I can send the notification. It always says undefined.

My index.js looks like this:

```
//listen for reply notification and then trigger a push notification
exports.observeNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{uid}/{commentId}/')
    .onCreate(event => {
        // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
        //const notification = event.data.val();
        console.log('User ID is: ', event.params.uid);
        console.log('Comment ID Is: ', event.params.commentId);
        return admin.database().ref('/users/' + event.params.uid).once('value', snapshot => {
            var userWeAreSendingTo = snapshot
            console.log('User ID is: ', userWeAreSendingTo);

            console.log('FCM Token of that user is: ', userWeAreSendingTo.fcmToken);

            var payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: "",
                    body: snapshot.content
                }
            };
            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userWeAreSendingTo.fcmToken, payload)
                .then((res) => {
                    // Response is a message ID string.
                    console.log('Successfully sent message:', res);
                    return true
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
                    return true
                })


        })
    })
```

This is a snapshot of the child node under the user node in my database.

```
   "9mzAHeX3lcdzriPdC4TfbRTkaUm2" : {
      "fcmToken" : "coC8uorosgc:APA91bGur2vvH4fwIProh87pUzVw0jYTOOFW3KfqWRVk4WdX0x8M1iBFwg28wM3tFyB5iRrowTWCZ_45oGwo0_7BFD6YvULE30NNZXxvE2O2XLjlLd_fqYwMfkndOqSUem2HqO-qvNcZ",
      "profilePic" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2F832F8156-C14A-4EF3-86EB-D8F4CFC784E5.PNG?alt=media&token=b9d11ea1-8cb3-4d0f-b111-b0baf567ac7b",
      "username" : "lol123"
    }
```

This screenshot of the console log

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1IPT.png)

Comment: `userWeAreSendingTo` doesn't have the value you think -- you should assign `snapshot.val()` to that variable, rather than just `snapshot`. I believe that will fix the issue you're having.

Comment: That's because the "snapshot" is info about the data, rather than the data itself. `snapshot.val()` gives you the actual data at the snapshot's location.

Comment: omg im so dumb thank you guys

Comment: wait that didn't do anythng I think

Comment: oh wait it worked